# How should I handle Simple Injector Lifestyles for MediatR NotificationHandlers?

Tags: asp.net, ioc-container, simple-injector, mediatr

I have an ASP.NET Web API using MediatR and SimpleInjector.

They are registered like this:

```cs
_container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();
_container.Options.DefaultLifestyle = Lifestyle.Scoped;

_container.Collection.Register(typeof(INotificationHandler<>), typesFound);
```

I can publish events from my `Controllers`:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<...> Get()
{
    _mediator.Publish(new SomeEvent());
}
```

That works perfectly!

A new requirement is to listen for updates from an external system (Tibco).  When an update occurs, the notification comes in via a C# event from another thread.  In the C# event handler, I want to use MediatR to `Publish` a notification:

```cs
void callbackFromTibco(object listener, MessageReceivedEventArgs @args)
{
    _mediatr.Publish(new SomeEvent();
}
```

It's at this point that SimpleInjector throws an exception:

`SomeEventHandler is registered as 'Async Scoped' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an active (Async Scoped) scope`.

That's because the call stack originates from another thread whereas in the `Controller`, the Controller itself was Scoped by SimpleInjector and hence MediatR creates the handler under the same scope.

Is it possible to do something so that I can register event handlers to be used in both circumstances?

I've gotten around this by creating an `IPublishEvents` interface and a `PublishEvents` class, where the `PublishEvents` class looks like:

```cs
public PublishEvents(Container container, IMediator mediator)
{
    _container = container;
    _mediator = mediator;
}

public Task Publish(object notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(_container))
    {
        return _mediator.Publish(notification, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Is the abstraction the right approach?  It certainly meets the `Don't Marry the Framework` mantra, but aside from that, I'd like to know if there's a better way...

Comment: I would say your solution is solid. Another option is to change your IMediator implementation.

Comment: Thanks @Steven- the `IMediator` implementation is the implementation from the MediatR pacakge.  Will continue with my approach now I've heard from the man himself (which essentially is just wrapping the MedaitR implementation)

Comment: @Steven - the Answer is yours if you'd like to post it as an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have three options:

- Define your own abstraction (as you are currently doing)
- Replace the default `IMediator` implementation with one that applies scoping
- Decorate the default `IMediator` implementation with a class that applies scoping

All three options are equally good, although defining your own application abstractions should typically have your preference, as that is in accordance to the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).